# Why $e^{PTP^{-1}}=Pe^TP^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

In the proof I read in the book, it looks like this:
$\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}$

$e^{\vec{PTP}^{-1}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{(\vec{P}{\vec{T}}\vec{P}^{-1})^k}{k!}=\underbrace{\vec{P} \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{{\vec{T}^k}}{k!}\vec{P}^{-1}}_{\text{step in question}}=\vec{P}e^{\vec{T}}\vec{P}^{-1}$.

I guess there's a property from *Linear Algebra* which I forgot. Would appreciate a reminder/clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take $$(\vec{P}\vec{T}\vec{P}^{-1})^k$$ you get 
$$\vec{P}\vec{T}\vec{P}^{-1}\vec{P}\vec{T}\vec{P}^{-1}\vec{P}\vec{T}\vec{P}^{-1}\cdots \vec{P}\vec{T}\vec{P}^{-1}$$ and you can see the there are $\vec{P}^{-1}\vec{P}$portions which evaluate to the identity matrix, so we are left with $$\vec{P}\vec{T}^k\vec{P}^{-1}$$ and then you can take out the $\vec{P}$ and $\vec{P}^{-1}$ from the sum because they are constant.